# Simulate mouse click on range input in HTML

Tags: javascript, onclick, range

I run into an issue when I have to simulate a click on a range input element in HTML. I thought it would be easy thing to do, since the method itself works on every other element. However, `range` input does not seem to work.

The method will simulate click on the given coordinates

```
function simulateClick(x, y) {
    let clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent('click', true, true);
    let element = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
    element.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);

    let marker = document.createElement('div');
marker.style.width = '4px';
    marker.style.height = '4px';
    marker.style.position = 'fixed';
    marker.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    marker.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    marker.style.left = x + 'px';
    marker.style.top = y + 'px';
    document.body.appendChild(marker);
}
```

Please see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3eqmzoLk/

After executing the code, the black dot simulates the click and the range handle should move to that desired position, however it does not work.

Comment: You should avoid using `createEvent` and `initEvent` as they are deprecated, trying using CustomEvent instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent